# alembic post migration commands

Tags: python, alembic

Due to some quirks in our database we need to reassign table owners post creation. Currently we leverage Alembic - has anyone got a simple way to create some sort of post hook that runs certain SQL commands after a migration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you're asking for can be resolved by editing the env.py file of alembic.. From [the docs](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/tutorial.html#the-migration-environment) (emphasis mine):

> env.py - The env.py script is part of the generated environment so that **the way
>   migrations run is entirely customizable**. The exact specifics of how to
>   connect are here, as well as the specifics of how the migration
>   environment are invoked. The script can be modified so that multiple
>   engines can be operated upon, custom arguments can be passed into the
>   migration environment, application-specific libraries and models can
>   be loaded in and made available.

I bet you could get the behavior you want by adding a call in `run_migrations_online()`.

(This is assuming you want to run the post_hook after EACH migration. If it was migration specific, you can update the `upgrade()` function in the generated migration file)