# How to VACUUM a SQLite database from within an Alembic migration?

Tags: python, sqlite, database-migration, alembic, vacuum

I am using [SqlAlchemy Alembic](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/) to perform DB migrations on a [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/) database. One of my migrations removes many redundant records and I would like to [`VACUUM`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html)  the database after the deletion.

Here's how I'm trying to do this in my migration's `upgrade()` method:

```
def upgrade():

    # deleting records here using op.execute()...

    op.execute("VACUUM")
```

When the migration runs it fails with this error message:

> ````
> E       sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) cannot VACUUM from within a transaction
> E       [SQL: VACUUM]
> E       (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)```
> ````

The link only provides a rather general description of what an `OperationalError` is.

**How can I overcome this error and VACUUM my database from within my migration?**

Is there a way to exclude this specific command or this specific migration from running in a transaction?

PS - In general I would like my migrations to run in transactions so I would prefer not to change Alembic's default behavior (as set in `env.py`).

Comment: you could commit before you do that.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44417335/alembic-post-migration-commands) answer your question?

Comment: @snakecharmerb thanks but no, as I prefer not to customize `env.py` for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to successfully execute the `VACUUM` command in my migration by wrapping it like so:

```
    with op.get_context().autocommit_block():
        op.execute("VACUUM")
```

This did not require any changes to `env.py`.